# File input output confusion

Tags: c++

I got conflicting advice with respect to how c++ operates with respect to reading past the eof.
The first group of people state that when the marker is reading past the eof area it reaches the eof and stops while the other group of people state it has to be in the exact position for it to be processed as reaching the eof. To make this clearer let me paste 2 blocks of code.

In this block of code, I am reading a number 1 from the file numbers.txt. They're no syntax errors and the only thing which I didn't paste over here is the code that opens the file.

```
while (!sample.eof())
{
    char ch;
    sample.get(ch);
    sample.seekp(-1L, ios::cur);
    sample >> initialnumber;
    sample.seekp(2L, ios::cur);
    cout << "OK";
}
```

In this program here I am reading the number 1 moving back one space making it start from the beginning processing it and then moving two spaces forward. The output for this is OK written only once.

```
#include < iostream>    
#include < fstream>
#include< string>

using namespace std;

string conversion(int);
int conversion2(string);

int main()
{

    string initialnumber;    
    fstream SAMPLE("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    ofstream sample2("numbers2.txt");    
    if (sample && sample2)     
    {
        int number2;
        string roman;
        int number;
        char ch;
        while (!sample.eof()) {
            sample.get(ch);    
            if (ch != '1' && ch != '2' && ch != '3' && ch != '4' && ch != '5' && ch != '6'
            && ch != '7' && ch != '8' && ch != '9') {
                SAMPLE.seekg(-1L, ios::cur);
                sample >> roman;
                sample.seekg(2L, ios::cur);
                sample2 << roman << " " << conversion2(roman) << endl;
                int L = sample.tellp();
                cout << L;
            }
            else {
                sample.seekg(-1L, ios::cur);
                sample >> number2;
                sample2 << conversion(number2) << " " << number2 << endl;
                sample.seekg(2L, ios::cur);
            }
        }
    } 
    else  
    {
        cout << "fail";
    }    
    sample.close();    
    sample2.close();
}
```

Here it is repeating the number infinite number of times when it shouldn't be repeating it meaning it never reached the eof.
Please help me understand the logic of both programs.

Comment: Maybe you should try to reduce the amount of posted code to obtain a minimal example. That would also help you in understanding the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C++11

```
Before doing anything else, seekg clears eofbit.
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg

Since `seekg` is always the last thing you call before checking `.eof()`, it will never be detected. The `eofbit` is set when a read operation hits the end of file. So, a read must be the last thing you do for it to work.

Comment: Then how come in the first program it actually exits the loop

Comment: Because it's calling `seekp`, which moves the write position, not `seekg`

Comment: genius this sums it up beautifully thanks for the help